# Connect multiple inputs type number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I need to make something like this. 6 input fields type number. 
Every label has `min` and `max`. The thing is if I put red 0 - 50 then yellow can not be from 49-70 it needs to automatically increase or decrease depending on the numbers around it so it always goes one after another? I am using React.

Is there some widgets for that or a way to connect multiple number inputs?

[image: input type text]

Comment: Hi, do you up and down the number one by one or with the keyboard ?

Comment: It should be possible by both. By keyboard and mouse one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to support keyboard input, you will have to update the ranges in the `onBlur` handler on the number inputs and change the input values in `onChange`. Here is an example with a custom `InputNumber` component which hides this onBlur/onChange detail:

```js
class InputNumber extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value
  }
  
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: +e.target.value });
  };
  
  onBlur = e => {
    this.props.onChange(this.state.value);
  };
  
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.value !== this.state.value) {
      this.setState({ value: nextProps.value });
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return <input
      type='number'
      {...this.props}
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      onBlur={this.onBlur}
    />;
  }
}

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ranges: [[1, 50], [51, 70], [71, 100]]
  };
  
  render() {
    const { rangeRed, rangeYellow, rangeGreen } = this.state;
    const controls = [
      this.range('Red Scoring Range', 'red', 0),
      this.range('Yellow Scoring Range', 'yellow', 1),
      this.range('Green Scoring Range', 'green', 2)
    ];
    return <table className='controls'>{controls}</table>;
  }
  
  range(label, color, idx) {
    const { ranges } = this.state;
    return (
      <tr className='control-row'>
        <td className='label'>{label}</td>
        <td><div className={color + ' bullet'}></div></td>
        <td>
          <InputNumber
            value={ranges[idx][0]}
            onChange={this.onChange(idx, true)}
            min={ranges[idx-1 < 0 ? 0 : idx-1][0] + 2}
            max={ranges[idx][1] - 1}
            disabled={idx === 0} />
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td>
          <InputNumber
            value={ranges[idx][1]}
            onChange={this.onChange(idx, false)}
            min={ranges[idx][0] + 1}
            max={ranges[(idx+1) % ranges.length][1]-2}
            disabled={idx === ranges.length-1} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
  
  onChange = (idx, isMin) => v => {
    const ranges = [...this.state.ranges];
    const min = isMin ? ranges[idx-1 < 0 ? 0 : idx-1][0] + 2 : ranges[idx][0] + 1;
    const max = isMin ? ranges[idx][1] - 1 : ranges[(idx+1) % ranges.length][1]-2;
    v = Math.min(Math.max(min, v), max);
    if (!isMin && idx < ranges.length-1) {
      ranges[idx][1] = v;
      ranges[idx+1][0] = v+1;
    } else if (isMin && idx > 0) {
      ranges[idx][0] = v;
      ranges[idx-1][1] = v-1;
    }
    this.setState({ ranges });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
:root {
  --bullet-size: 15px;
}

* {
  color: #555;
}

.bullet {
  display: inline-block;
  height: var(--bullet-size);
  width: var(--bullet-size);
  border-radius: var(--bullet-size);
}

.red { background: red; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
.green { background: green; }

td { padding: 5px; }

input {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you want instantaneous range updates and do not care about keyboard input, then update the ranges directly in the `onChange` handler:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ranges: [0, 50, 70, 100]
  };
  
  render() {
    const { rangeRed, rangeYellow, rangeGreen } = this.state;
    const controls = [
      this.range('Red Scoring Range', 'red', 0),
      this.range('Yellow Scoring Range', 'yellow', 1),
      this.range('Green Scoring Range', 'green', 2)
    ];
    return <table className='controls'>{controls}</table>;
  }
  
  range(label, color, idx) {
    const { ranges } = this.state;
    return (
      <tr className='control-row'>
        <td className='label'>{label}</td>
        <td><div className={color + ' bullet'}></div></td>
        <td>
          <input
            type='number'
            value={ranges[idx] + 1}
            onChange={this.onChange(idx, true)}
            max={ranges[idx+1] - 1}
            disabled={idx === 0} />
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td>
          <input
            type='number'
            value={ranges[idx+1]}
            onChange={this.onChange(idx+1, false)}
            min={ranges[idx] + 1}
            disabled={idx+1 === ranges.length-1} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  onChange = (idx, isMin) => e => {
    const ranges = [...this.state.ranges];
    const value = isMin ? +e.target.value - 1 : +e.target.value;
    if (isMin && value > ranges[idx - 1] + 1 && value < ranges[idx + 1] + 1)
      ranges[idx] = value;
    if (!isMin && value < ranges[idx + 1] - 1 && value > ranges[idx - 1] + 1)
      ranges[idx] = value;
    this.setState({ ranges });
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
:root {
  --bullet-size: 15px;
}

* {
  color: #555;
}

.bullet {
  display: inline-block;
  height: var(--bullet-size);
  width: var(--bullet-size);
  border-radius: var(--bullet-size);
}

.red { background: red; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
.green { background: green; }

td { padding: 5px; }

input {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: hi jo_va, thank you for your effort. I will take a look. I tried the code snippet and found two problems. If I start to decrease for example red max, yellow min is not decreasing. Also for example red max and yellow min can never be the same.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, oh I thought you wanted to update the neighbouring ranges only when a collision happens... my bad, I will update my answer

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, I updated the answer, could you have a look ?

Comment: @jo-va thank you. I still see a few problems.
1. If red max is 20 then yellow min should be 21, not 20
2. if yellow min is 20 and yellow max is 25, then yellow min should be able to come to 24 and not higher then that
3. red min and green max should be disabled

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, it took quite a few edits, but it should all be fixed now! Hope it helps :)

Comment: @jo-va thank you for your help, I just have one problem that I can not enter with keyboard numbers into yellow min and max and green min. I can enter it into red max.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, this problem comes from onChange updating the value as you type, you need to cache the values in onChange and set update the ranges in onBlur, I will leave it to you as this part was not mentionned in your question

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, I updated the code and added a snippet with keyboard input, it is a bit more complex however. This technique however only updates the ranges on blur, you can't have both at the same time

Comment: @jo-va thank you. In keyboard input I have some problem with somebody for example enters more then 100 for yellow max it should be put automatically one lower then red min, but thank you I was managed to do what I needed.

Comment: @Igor-Vuk, I added a check in the onChange function to clamp the value to the same min/max set on the Input fields

Answer (score 0):

You can dinamically set the values of your input in the state and trigger an event to change these attribute depending on wich label change.

After you set the min and max by the previous or next input value

For exemple :

```
class YouClass extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props)
    this.state = {
     redMaxValue: 50,
     yellowMinValue: 51,
     yellowMaxValue: 70,
     greenMinValue: 71,
   }
 }


 onChangeMaxRed = e =>{
    this.setState({redMaxValue : e.target.value});

    if(e.target.value >= this.state.yellowMinValue){
      this.setState({yellowMinValue: e.target.value +1});
    }
 }






render(){

 return(){

<div>
   <input type="number" value="0" disabled />
   <input type="number" value={this.state.redMaxValue} min="1" max={this.state.yellowMinValue} onChange={this.onChangeMaxRed} />


  <input type="number" value={this.state.yellowMinValue} min={this.state.yellowMaxValue -1} max={yellowMaxValue -1} />
  <input type="number" value={this.state.yellowMaxValue}" min={this.state.yellowMinValue + 1}  max={redMinValue}/>




   <input type="number" value={this.state.greenMinValue} min={this.state.yellowMaxValue} max={99} />
    <input type="number" value="100" disabled />

</div>

 }   

}

}
```

I didn't write all of the onChange function, i think you get the thing.

A simpler version is without min and max attributes and just values.